# Reacts js Ant Design multiple input slider handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, antd

I have multiple elements in the state, and when input slider is dragged i want to set the value into state elements, i've tried to write one function that will setState for the dragged elements in state but it isn't working

Here's what i've tried. When slider changes in the browser it shows -- Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

Can anyone help to solve this problem. I just want to set slider value into state with one function.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import './table.css';
import { Table, Slider, InputNumber, Row, Col } from 'antd';



export default class TableRender extends Component{
    state = {
        averageCheck: 0,
        newSales: 0,
        customerChurn:0,
        reSales:0,
        totalSales:0,
        advertisingBudget: 0,
        advertisingAgency: 0,
        kpi:0,
        salesManager:0,
    };


    handleChange=(event)=>{
        let nam = event.target.name;
        let val = event.target.value;
        this.setState({[nam]: val});
        console.log(nam)
    };
render(){
    const { averageCheck, newSales, customerChurn } = this.state;
   
   return (
          <div className="slider1">
                        <h2>Tovar</h2>
                        <p>Tovar o'rtacha qiymati</p>
                        <Row>
                            <Col span={12}>
                                <Slider
                                    name="averageCheck"
                                    min={10000}
                                    max={30000000}
                                    step={5000}
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                    value={typeof averageCheck === 'number' ? averageCheck : 0}
                                />
                            </Col>
                            <Col span={2}>
                                <InputNumber
                                    min={10000}
                                    max={30000000}
                                    step={5000}
                                    style={{ margin: '0 16px' }}
                                    value={averageCheck}
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                />
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                        <p>Yangi Sotuvlar</p>
                        <Row>
                            <Col span={12}>
                                <Slider
                                    name="newSales"
                                    min={1000000}
                                    max={30000000}
                                    step={5000}
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                    value={typeof newSales === 'number' ? newSales : 0}
                                />
                            </Col>
                            <Col span={2}>
                                <InputNumber
                                    min={1000000}
                                    max={30000000}
                                    step={5000}
                                    style={{ margin: '0 16px' }}
                                    value={newSales}
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                />
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                        <p>Xaridor Kamayishi, %</p>
                        <Row>
                            <Col span={12}>
                                <Slider
                                    name="customerChurn"
                                    min={1}
                                    max={100}
                                    step={1}
                                    marks={marks}
                                    style={{ borderColor: 'green' }}
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                    value={typeof customerChurn === 'number' ? customerChurn : 0}
                                />
                            </Col>
                            <Col span={2}>
                                <InputNumber
                                    min={1}
                                    max={100}
                                    step={1}
                                    style={{ margin: '0 16px' }}
                                    value={customerChurn}
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                />
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </div>
          )
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The antd `Slider` `onChange` callback return a value not an event object that's why its give you an error of accessing undefined. Try to modify the `onChange` callback like this:

```
<Slider
  min={10000}
  max={30000000}
  step={5000}
  onChange={(value) => this.handleChange("averageCheck", value)}
  value={typeof averageCheck === "number" ? averageCheck : 0}
/>;
```

and in your handleChange function:

```
handleChange = (name, value) => {
  let nam = name;
  let val = value;
  this.setState({ [nam]: val });
  console.log(nam);
};
```

It can be also applied on your `InputNumber` so you are still using one function